# Usage of SHGetSpecialFolderPath to retrieve an application folder that can be accessed also to non admin users, which CSIDL to choose?

Tags: delphi, winapi, special-folders

In my application I store on every machine some files in an application folder.

A simplified version of the real case is this:

```
..\Project1\LoginHistory (login history file - common for all users)
..\Project1\Translations (localization files - common for all users)
..\Project1\FormSettings\User1\ (this contains an ini file per form for User1)
..\Project1\FormSettings\UserN\ (this contains an ini file per form for UserN)
```

So you can see why I use this: to save some data that is specific to the machine (remember the latest logins made from this machine, a kind of MRU), to store Translation strings or 3rd party components (these are extracted runtime from exe resources) and for saving some user specific data (like form size). The real case is more complex, but at least you can get that there are some "common folder" and some "user folders".

Now I would like to keep this structure, so all my files in a single ..\Project1 folder (+ subfolders). Even because the users are not the windows users, but they are SQL Server users.

My question is which folder to choose for `..\`.

Currently I am (succesfully) using this code for retrieveing `..\`

```
uses ShlObj;

function GetSpecialFolder(const CSIDL: integer) : string;
var
  RecPath : PWideChar;
begin
  RecPath := StrAlloc(MAX_PATH);
    try
    FillChar(RecPath^, MAX_PATH, 0);
    if SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, RecPath, CSIDL, false) 
      then result := RecPath
      else result := '';
    finally
      StrDispose(RecPath);
    end;
end;
```

And I call it with

```
GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_APPDATA)
```

Where the list of CDISL is defined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

`GetSpecialFolder(CSIDL_APPDATA)` returns `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming` in Windows 7.

So this used to work, but recently I recieved some complaint from some customer that seems directly related to read/write problems in these folders. (for example `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Project1\LoginHistory` - using folders listed above).

So my question is: is it correct to use `CSIDL_APPDATA`? Do you have another suggestion? Is there a chance that on some OS or with some users with really reduced privileges there can be read/write problems on that folder?

Please remember that I would not like to have more than one root folder for my files.

Comment: Users have to be able to write there. Otherwise the whole system breaks down. Do you perhaps need to create missing directories before writing files? It's hard to debug this if you don't tell us the error code and message!!

Comment: Yes, if the user cannot write of course the whole idea is not working. I am not able to reproduce the problem, I am just been told that someone has this problem, so I am trying to guess which is the reason. Probabyl I will have a chance to investigate it further, but not now. This is why I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I use finally is correct. Since I do not really need common files for my application (it makes sense that all the temp files are user specific - because the few common things are stored in the DB) `CSIDL_APPDATA` is a good place.

The problem I was facing it is still not clear but I suspect it is due to the fact that login.ini is a reserved word (only recently, after some recent windows update maybe).

I already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324543/is-login-ini-a-reserved-name).

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to use `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` for files that are not user-specific.  If you assumed (in your code) that files stored in `CSIDL_APPDATA` are shared among users, that is not allowed.

Comment: But you mean that a user with "no privileges on the machine", let's say a kind of "guest" user can read write from `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` and not from `CSIDL_APPDATA`? I mean by changing to `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` are there chances that things will go better or not? Or you are suggesting this just because "semantically" it would be a better choice (and I agree with you)?

Comment: Just to confirm: `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` is 100% better, here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx) they say also that "This information will not roam and is available to anyone using the computer.". While this is not written for `CSIDL_APPDATA`.

Comment: I have one more comment: and what happens in a terminal server scenario? In that case more users will be using the same folder and this could be a problem.

Comment: By reading this question (http://www.delphigroups.info/3/1/57528.html) I see that also the COMMON solution has the same problem. The problem is that a basic user is not able to create folders probably. So what to do? My app has not an installer, it is just a plain exe that user runs, and this is very convenient and for no reason I want to change this, could you suggest another place where to store files?

Comment: Another comment (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowssecurity/thread/e87516e7-8983-45bc-ba9e-e32c3e748b73). So probably i should find another place, common documents?

Comment: It comes down to whether or not you want the settings associated with the user or the machine.

Comment: For some things yes (like login history I want it to be he login history of this machine), so it is ok for me to keep all my data in a special folder that contains "username" in the path. This said, is there one Special Folder in which I am sure even the dummiest user can be able so write folders and create files?