# Is "login.ini" a reserved name?

Tags: windows, ini, reserved-words

I store the MRU of logins to my application in a file called login.ini and I save it in widnows application folders.

I noticed that on some systems — I don't know why; I cannot find a common cause — the user cannot create the file, whereas it creates all other files in the same folder.

The only reason I can think of is that some antivirus/windows setting/... doesn't allow this particular user to create the file on this system.

I solved the problem by renaming the file and it seems ok, but I'd like to be sure. Does anyone know more?

**Note for bounty:**

[This is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089877/usage-of-shgetspecialfolderpath-to-retrieve-an-application-folder-that-can-be-acc/5484533#5484533) I asked that details a little more what I am doing.

Comment: What do you mean windows application folders - you mean you're storing them in `C:\Program Files\My Application`? That's not where it should go. If it's a common file across users then (I think) it really belongs in what used to be All Users\Application Settings but I think is now ProgramData ([CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [FOLDERID_ProgramData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Of course this isn't directly relevant to your question - I'm still interested to hear about login.ini.

Comment: yes i mean in CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA

Comment: @user193655: Do you have a GetLastError() value (assuming native code) or a more descriptive exception error message (assuming managed) from your attempt to create the file that might shed light on the issue?

Comment: what is the error code returned on create? also have you tried using procmon at the time of attempted creation?

Comment: I'm pretty sure login.ini is not a reserved Windows name, otherwise we would find it with google. As steelbytes said, plese use procmon, and at least it will tell you if another process uses it. If no other process uses it, the problem lies in your code.

Comment: Unfortunately that exception is not handled, moreover using ProcMon is very difficult because this happens only to some customers where I have restricted access, so being able to use ProcMon requires filling complicated forms and asking for special permissions. I can of course handle the exception and prepare a special build, but those are all things that are an overhead for me (since it appears that renaming the file fixed the problem). So I asked this question to have some feedback from other developers and avoid going into the process I just described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little Google-fu turns up that other Windows developers have sucessfully created login.ini for their programs, and others use it in a third-party Windows login management program, so I would expect that its "reservedness" is partially dependent on its location in the file system (i.e. in the system files). However, I don't think the name "login.ini" is a system-wide reserved name, no.

I think you're right - certain antivirus programs MAY be messing with the creation of that file, as it is a fairly likely candidate imho for a virus filename. It looks as if it may already have been used for that purpose somewhere (apparently outside of the US), tho don't quote me on that.

So, if a different name works for you, I'd go with that. :)

Comment: Even if this doesn't totally answer, at least it confirms my theory.

Answer (score 3):

Anti-virus is a definite possibility for messing with your file. Stuff like that happened all the time to me when I was using Norton.
'login.ini' is not a system-wide reserved name, it would only mess things up with the OS if you had it in the (assuming your drive is C:) C:\WINDOWS or C:\WINDOWS\System32 directories.
If you just have the file in an application files directory (like C:\Program Files or C:\All Users\Application Settings and such) it shouldn't interfere with the system.
If you determine that anti-virus is a definite problem, you could change the name to something like loginData and maybe make up a new file extension if you want to (assuming you are just going to read the file from a program, where the extension doesn't matter. otherwise stick to a recognized file extension)